# Lotus Notes 8 client cannot be restarted after crash

Tags: reboot, lotus-notes, tasks

The client can not be restarted, even if the notes.exe and nlotes.exe tasks stopped in the task manager.
Only rebooting helps, but that is not a user friendly solution. This occures on Lenovo laptops.
How to restart the client only? Is there any additional task should be stopped?

Comment: What happens when you try to restart the client? Do error messages appear, for instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some people will suggest KillNotes to you, but this can cause corruption.

The better way is to go into the notes folder and run the following command.

```
nsd -kill
```

It should remove all processes that will stop it rebooting.

Alternatively on the start menu you can use the following.

*Lotus Applications -> Support -> Collect Lotus Notes diagnostic data and exit Notes*